# How do I check if the battery has been calibrated on my Macbook Pro?

Tags: battery

How can I check if the battery calibration has been done properly?

I followed Apple's steps precisely, but I see no change in the loadCycles, or battery capacity using CoconutBattery.

Comment: Excellent question. Was asking myself how to know I did it right. Your cycle count should have done a +1!

Answer (score 2):

Everything you need should be here:
http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1490

There is no indication as such that you've done it 'properly', other than your 'Cycle count' (in System Profiler -> Hardware -> Power) will go up by one. However calibration doesn't necessarily affect your battery capacity immediately; instead it improves the longevity of your battery, and the accuracy of the battery life readings (in your menu bar) when your laptop is unplugged.

Comment: You might add that calibration process permits MacOS X to approch a more lower battery level. Hence you have a longer autonomy on battery between *fully charged* and *on the reserve* (which is slightly above *fully empty*).

Comment: @iguanarama "It improves the longevity of your battery" -- Is there any data / research behind this statement? I've seen it multiple times, but never with reasoning behind it.